# Use of pipe character in VCF info field

Tags: bioinformatics, gene-annotation, variant

While annotating my VCF file with ClinVar, I noted the following value for the `CLNSIG` field (i.e., clinical significance):

```
CLNSIG=2|2|2|2|2|2|2
```

This is actually reported in [this example](https://github.com/WGLab/doc-ANNOVAR/issues/5), so I think the usage of the pipe is quite common for genomic annotations of this kind.

Which is the use of the pipe (`|`) character? I looked for it in the VCF file format specification; however, only the meaning of the comma (`,`) is specified (i.e., presence of multiple alternate value for that field). I am wondering, instead, what the pipe represents.

Thank you.

Comment: There's [some documentation](http://geneontology.org/page/go-annotation-file-gaf-format-21) on the GO annotation (GAF) format which goes on to define the pipe to mean 'OR'. I think this is somewhat supported by the NCBI gene annotation format for gene names e.g. *BRCAI | BRCC1 | BROVCA1 | FANCS | IRIS | PNCA4 | PPP1R53 | PSCP | RNF53*. But it may still be specific for VCF, so I will dig a little more but if nothing else this is my understanding.

Comment: This was my suspect, actually. I think that, e.g., an annotation string such as `GENEINFO=BRCA1|BRCC1,BRCA1|FANCS` could mean that the `GENEINFO` annotation can take two possible values, each one suggested by a different annotation source: 1) `BRCA1|BRCC1`: the first annotation source suggests that the variant is located either on `BRCA1` or on `BRCC1`; 2) `BRCA1|FANCS`: the second annotation source suggests that the variant is located either on `BRCA1` or on `FANCS`. I cannot find any documentation, though, so I am not sure this is the right interpretation.

Comment: Yet another question that could have fit in a [bioinformatics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97204/bioinformatics) stackexchange...

Comment: @bli I completely agree with you. Unfortunately, Biology Stackexchange mixes biology and bioinformatics, and there is not a way of separating the two aspects. However, I agree that bioinformatics should have its own identity.

Comment: @bli https://www.biostars.org/ is so established at this point it diminishes the need for a bioinformatics SE other than having that integration with the other communities here (which would be nice, honestly).